# No me muestra la información del tiempo Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, api

Estoy haciendo una aplicación sencilla en android studio, pones una ciudad y te dice el tiempo. La pregunta es tengo todo el código hecho y en la APP al poner una ciudad y darle a "mira el tiempo" no hace absolutamente nada. La APP conecta con una api de openweather. Cabe decir que al compilar no da absolutamente ningún error.

```
package com.example.enero1701;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
/*Projecto Tiempo Ciudad*/

    EditText ciudad;
    TextView tiempo;
    Button consulta;
    String url_ciudad;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ciudad = findViewById((R.id.ciudad));
        tiempo = findViewById(R.id.tiempo);
        consulta = findViewById(R.id.tiempoButton);

        consulta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                url_ciudad= ciudad.getText().toString();
            }
        });

        Mihilo hilo = new Mihilo();
        hilo.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + url_ciudad + "&APPID=67fe87868797df83ee6c2d6885af93e1");
        //Donde va el nombre de la ciudad concatenar url_ciudad
    }


    public class Mihilo extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            HttpURLConnection connection;
            URL url;
            String result;
            result = "";

            try {
                // conectarse a servidor web
                url = new URL(strings[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputstream = connection.getInputStream();

                int data = inputstream.read();

                while (data != -1) {
                    result += (char) data;
                    data = inputstream.read();
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.i("RESULT", result);
            return result;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String data){
            super.onPostExecute(data);

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("weather");

                Log.i(("WEATHER"), jsonArray.toString());

                for (int i = 0 ; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject jsonitem = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    tiempo.setText(jsonitem.getString("description"));
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: has copiado el codigo de algun lado???

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez nooo

Comment: lo probe con la respuesta que te deje y funciono

Answer (score 0):

Tu codigo parece estar bien, sin embargo no se por que funciona con:

```
tiempo.setText(jsonitem.getString("description"));
```

Prueba recogiendo en un String el valor antes:

```
String descripcion = jsonitem.getString("description");

tiempo.setText(descripcion);
```

Comment: Perdón, por la demora. Me sigue son funcionar el código, lo he puesto cogiendo el valor del String antes pero no hace nada igual.